# How to set s:hidden value from another JSP element

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

i have following form :

```
<s:form id="storno_form"
    namespace="namespace"
    action="action">

    <sj:submit id="submitId"
        key="btn.show" targets="cancelation_content"
        cssClass="button" validate="true">
    </sj:submit>
</s:form>
```

and outside the form is :

```
<sj:select
    href="%{getUrl}"
    id="selectCampaign"
    autocomplete="true"
    selectBoxIcon="true"
    key="select.campaign"
    name="campaignId"
    list="campaigns"
    listKey="id"
    listValue="name"
    headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="%{getText('select.headerValue')}"
    onSelectTopics="realod"
    onCompleteTopics="customizeAutoCompleter"
/>
```

how can i submit the value of the select element with the form:
i have tried :

```
<s:form id="storno_form"
    namespace="namespace"
    action="action">
    <s:hidden  value="%{'campaignId'}" name="campaignId" />
    <sj:submit id="submitId"
        key="btn.show" targets="cancelation_content"
        cssClass="button" validate="true">
    </sj:submit>
</s:form>
```

but its not working ?

Comment: I didn't really read the whole thing, but considering it's an issue with the hidden value you realize the expression %{'campaignId'} will always evaluate to "campaignId". campaignId without quotes will look on the action and more than one character with single quotes will evaluate to a String (single character to a char, and then everything turns into a String on output of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with javascript

```
onchange="var el=document.getElementById('selectCampaign');document.getElementById('storno_form')['campaignId'].value=el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;"
```

the same you can do `onclick` event of `<sj:submit` tag.

with jQuery it's even easier

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectCampagn').change(function() {
   var val = $('#selectCampagn').val();
    $('input[name=campaignId]').val(val);
  });
});
```